# What's the easiest way to determine if a method call will run under Medium Trust?

Tags: asp.net, security

Is there a quick way to determine if a method call will run under medium trust?  In this scenario, I'm specifically wanting to know about trust-level requirements for .NET Framework methods.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check MSDN or use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to check attributes.

This is just an example of the type of attribute you will be looking for.

```
[AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Level=AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]
public static class ProfileManager
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set trust level medium in your web.config file

Comment: @adeel, how does that determine if a method/class will run in medium trust, exactly?